# www on localhost - Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Tags: web-config, global-asax

When I sit and work on localhost and gives me www oven in the hat so that I can run my website localhost. Thus, I can only run it on the server.

I've looked in global.asax and web.config file.

What can the problem guilt? it happened after I add www in web.config but as I saw it then does not work on localhost so I took it away again. and since it has not worked.

U can see it problem her:

[image]